# Change width of the inner view where inner view's width is dependent on the outer view.

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

It would be awesome if anyone would guide me to the right solution here. It's my second question of the day over here, and I am kind hesitant to ask it over here but I am learning totally new stuff(like creating your own segmented control etc) and have literally no idea where to even begin with this error. I have tried to debug as much as possible with my limited knowledge.

***So here's my problem in the summary form.***

I have two views. Inner view's width is dependent on the outer view's width. So If I update my outer View's width Constraint(using constraint IBoutlet), outer view's width changes but the inner views width remains the sameas the old one. I did layoutIfNeeded() on the outer view after I change the width constraint of the outer view but nothing happens.

***In detail:***

I have a segmented control(outer view) which selector's width(inner view) is dependent on the segmented control's total width. As I said above, the width of the selector remains the same after I change the the total width of the segmented control.  Selector's width is dependent on the segmented control's width.

Here's the image illustrating my problem.

[image]

As you can see my selector's width is not getting updated. It should be half of the total width of the new segmented control.

***How I updated my segmented control's width?***

Basically I took the width constraint of the segmented control as an IBOUtlet in my VC then I increased it's width according to the screen size. But the selector's width remain same.

HERE'S THE CODE that I used to changed my width of my segmented control

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.segmentedWidthControl.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2
    self.segmentedControl.layoutIfNeeded()
  //self.segmentedControl.updateConstraints() // this doesn't work either
    }
```

For the custom segmented control, I followed tutorial from the youtube. 
Here's the code

```
@IBDesignable
class SegmentedControl: UIControl{

var buttons = [UIButton]()

var selector: UIView!

var selectSegmentIndex = 0

@IBInspectable
var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0{

    didSet{
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}
@IBInspectable
var borderColor: UIColor = .clear {

    didSet{
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    }
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    layer.cornerRadius = frame.height/2
}

@IBInspectable
var commaSeperatedButtonTitles: String = ""{
    didSet{

        updateView()
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var selectorColor: UIColor = .white{

    didSet{
         updateView()
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var selectorTextColor: UIColor = .white{

    didSet{
        updateView()
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var TextColor: UIColor = .lightGray {

    didSet{
        updateView()

    }
}



func  updateView(){

    buttons.removeAll()

    subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview()}

    let buttonTitles =  commaSeperatedButtonTitles.components(separatedBy: ",")
    for buttonTitle in buttonTitles{
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(TextColor, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(button: )), for: .touchUpInside )
        buttons.append(button)
    }

    buttons[0].setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)


    let selectorWidth = frame.width/CGFloat(buttonTitles.count)

    selector = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: selectorWidth, height: frame.height))
    selector.backgroundColor = selectorColor
    selector.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    selector.layer.cornerRadius = frame.height/2

    addSubview(selector)

    let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttons)
    sv.axis = .horizontal
    sv.alignment = .fill
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.distribution = .fillEqually

    addSubview(sv)
    sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    sv.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
    sv.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true



}

@objc func buttonTapped(button:UIButton){
    for (buttonIndex,btn) in buttons.enumerated(){
        btn.setTitleColor(TextColor, for: .normal)
        if(btn == button){
            selectSegmentIndex = buttonIndex
            let selectorStartPosition = frame.width/CGFloat(buttons.count) * CGFloat(buttonIndex)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.selector.frame.origin.x = selectorStartPosition
            }
            btn.setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
        }
    }

    sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
}
```

}

Here's the GITHUB link if you want to run the app. https://github.com/Rikenm/Auto-Counter-iOS

And lastly thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to change the width of your custom control *while it is visible*? Such as in response to a user action? Or only when it is initially displayed?

Comment: only when it is initially displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd highly recommend using constraints and auto-layout, rather than explicitly setting frames.

Here is your custom class, with really only a few changes. I've commented everything I did:

```
@IBDesignable
class SegmentedControl: UIControl{

    var buttons = [UIButton]()

    var selector: UIView!

    var selectSegmentIndex = 0

    // leading constraint for selector view
    var selectorLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0{

        didSet{
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor = .clear {

        didSet{
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height/2
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var commaSeperatedButtonTitles: String = ""{
        didSet{

            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var selectorColor: UIColor = .white{

        didSet{
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var selectorTextColor: UIColor = .white{

        didSet{
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var TextColor: UIColor = .lightGray {

        didSet{
            updateView()

        }
    }

    // this will update the control in IB
    // when constraints are changed
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        updateView()
    }

    // this will keep the selector corners "round"
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        selector.layer.cornerRadius = selector.frame.height / 2.0
    }

    func  updateView(){

        buttons.removeAll()

        subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview()}

        let buttonTitles =  commaSeperatedButtonTitles.components(separatedBy: ",")
        for buttonTitle in buttonTitles{
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(TextColor, for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(button: )), for: .touchUpInside )
            buttons.append(button)
        }

        buttons[0].setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)

        // not needed
        //let selectorWidth = frame.width/CGFloat(buttonTitles.count)

        // we're going to use auto-layout, so no need to set a frame
        //selector = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: selectorWidth, height: frame.height))
        selector = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

        selector.backgroundColor = selectorColor
        selector.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        selector.layer.cornerRadius = frame.height/2

        addSubview(selector)

        // constrain selector top to self.top
        selector.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        // constrain selector height to self.height
        selector.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        // constrain selector width to self.width
        // with multiplier of 1 / number of buttons
        let m = 1.0 / CGFloat(buttons.count)
        selector.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: m).isActive = true

        // instantiate leading constraint for selector, and
        // keep a reference in var selectorLeadingConstraint
        selectorLeadingConstraint = selector.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0)

        // make it active
        selectorLeadingConstraint.isActive = true

        let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttons)
        sv.axis = .horizontal
        sv.alignment = .fill
        //        sv.distribution = .fillProportionally
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.distribution = .fillEqually

        addSubview(sv)
        sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        sv.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        sv.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func buttonTapped(button:UIButton){
        for (buttonIndex,btn) in buttons.enumerated(){
            btn.setTitleColor(TextColor, for: .normal)
            if(btn == button){
                selectSegmentIndex = buttonIndex
                let selectorStartPosition = frame.width/CGFloat(buttons.count) * CGFloat(buttonIndex)

                    // update selector's leading constraint, instead of explicit frame
                    //self.selector.frame.origin.x = selectorStartPosition
                    self.selectorLeadingConstraint.constant = selectorStartPosition

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
                btn.setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
            }
        }

        sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
    }

}
```

---

**Edit:**

Here is another option. Instead of using a `UIStackView`, use constraints to layout the buttons. The "selector" view will now be a *sibling* of the buttons, so you can use a `centerX` constraint instead of calculating the `.leadingAnchor` constraint.

The big benefit is that now you can change the size of the custom segmented control *after* it has been displayed, and the "selector" size and position will update automatically. For example, if you set the width of the control to 50% of the width of the screen (or its superview), and then you rotate the device so the control gets wider or narrower.

```
@IBDesignable
class SegmentedControl: UIControl{

    var buttons = [UIButton]()

    var selector: UIView!

    // centerX constraint for selector view
    var selectorCenterXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0{

        didSet{
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor = .clear {

        didSet{
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height/2
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var commaSeperatedButtonTitles: String = ""{
        didSet{

            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var selectorColor: UIColor = .white{

        didSet{
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var selectorTextColor: UIColor = .white{

        didSet{
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var TextColor: UIColor = .lightGray {

        didSet{
            updateView()

        }
    }

    // this will update the control in IB
    // when constraints are changed
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        updateView()
    }

    // this will keep the selector corners "round"
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        selector.layer.cornerRadius = selector.frame.height / 2.0
    }

    func  updateView(){

        buttons.removeAll()

        subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview()}

        // deactivate centerX constraint if its been initialized
        if selectorCenterXConstraint != nil {
            selectorCenterXConstraint.isActive = false
        }

        // add the selector view first
        selector = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

        selector.backgroundColor = selectorColor
        selector.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        selector.layer.cornerRadius = frame.height/2

        addSubview(selector)

        let buttonTitles =  commaSeperatedButtonTitles.components(separatedBy: ",")
        for buttonTitle in buttonTitles{
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(TextColor, for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(button: )), for: .touchUpInside )
            buttons.append(button)
        }

        buttons[0].setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)

        // add each button and set top and height constraints
        buttons.forEach {
            self.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
            $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        // constrain first button's leading to self.leading
        // constrain last button's trailing to self.trailing
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            buttons[0].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            buttons[buttons.count - 1].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
        ])

        // constrain each button's width to the first button's width
        for i in 1..<buttons.count {
            buttons[i].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttons[i - 1].trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            buttons[i].widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttons[0].widthAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        // constrain selector top, height and width to first button's top, height and width
        selector.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttons[0].topAnchor).isActive = true
        selector.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttons[0].heightAnchor).isActive = true
        selector.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttons[0].widthAnchor).isActive = true

        // constrain selector's centerX to first button's centerX
        selectorCenterXConstraint = selector.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttons[0].centerXAnchor)
        selectorCenterXConstraint.isActive = true

    }

    @objc func buttonTapped(button:UIButton){
        buttons.forEach { btn in
            btn.setTitleColor(TextColor, for: .normal)
            if (btn == button) {

                // deactivate selector's current centerX constraint
                self.selectorCenterXConstraint.isActive = false

                // constrain selector's centerX to selected button's centerX
                self.selectorCenterXConstraint = self.selector.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.centerXAnchor)

                // re-activate selector's centerX constraint
                self.selectorCenterXConstraint.isActive = true

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
                btn.setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
            }
        }

        sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
    }

}
```

---

One tip for posting questions here --- read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The easies solution would be to override `layoutSubviews` and update the width of the `selector` view.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    selector.frame.width = frame.width / CGFloat(buttons.count)
}
```

But you could also have antoayout do it automatically by constraining the selector view to have the same width as the segmented controller with a multiplier of `1/buttons.count`